# VB 6 ActiveX to .net and Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, vb6, activex, vb6-migration

I have an activex control that is written in VB 6.
That activex is used to display in Internet Explorer.

I would like to extend that code.

I have 2 options -

1. To convert it to .net(preferred c#)
2. To Extend the vb 6 code

My questions are:

**If I choose the first option**

Is it possible to convert an activex to .net and view that in Internet Explorer?

*I used aximp (active x wrapper for .net) to wrap the activex and registered my .net user 
control as COM. Then tryed to display the user control in Internet Explorer - and what happened is that I see my user control(I added text to seperate between the activex to the user control) - but not the activex object.
BTW - I don't want it to be installed in the GAC because I the activex uses many other files that should be relative to it.*

**If I choose the second option -**

How do I compile that code?(should be simple but I can't find any free VB 6 compiler)

Comment: @bjan: That would have a +1 if you didn't suggest they steal it...

Comment: @Deanna, If `steal` sounds like `suggestion` then i should be blamed. Otherwise, `Pay` and `steal` are two ways which @OP would already know, now it is up to @OP to decide which way s/he chooses and i believe s/he would be mature enough to decide what is right and what is wrong

Comment: @bjan: Maybe "acquire" would have been a better word leaving the ethics up to them. Listing "steal" as an option is just wrong.

Comment: There were/are no express editions for Visual Studio 6, the only IDE (compiler) for VB6, so you have to acquire Visual Studio 6 for option 2

Answer (score 0):

You have already answered the first part of your question.

The second part answer is that you will need to get a copy of Visual Basic 6 to be able to compile your ActiveX control. You can [buy this on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00002S7I0) or if you have an MSDN subscription you may be able to download as part of the subscription.